# Simple one-vector input arrays seen as incompatible by scikit

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have two variables both originally from the same pandas df. I extract one to TT and the other to t. I'm using TT to predict t, which is binary. I can't determine why the variables are seen as having incompatible shapes by scikit. I've transposed TT as a fix but that didn't work.

```
>>> TT=adf.x1.values
>>> t=adf.y.values
>>> TT.shape
(2856L,)
>>> t.shape
(2856L,)
>>> TT
array([ 4.43081665,  5.99146461,  4.86753464, ...,  4.58496761,
        8.4553175 ,  7.37775898], dtype=float32)
>>> t
array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
>>> clf=LogisticRegression(C=1)   
>>> clf.fit(TT,t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:...\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 686, in fit
        (X.shape[0], y.shape[0]))
ValueError: X and y have incompatible shapes.
X has 1 samples, but y has 2856.)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check out the documentation on [`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit),

- `TT` should have shape `(n_samples, n_features)`, and
- `t` should have shape `(n_samples)`.

Your `TT` vector should be a 2D array. You can reshape `TT` to have shape (2856L, 1) by doing `TT.reshape(-1, 1)` and that will at least get rid of the error, but I'm not sure if that gives the desired result.